# What is the difference between struct{a int;b int} and struct{b int;a int}?

Tags: types, go

What is the difference between these two structs other than that they aren't considered equivalent?

```
package main
func main() {}
func f1(s struct{a int;b int}) { f2(s) }
func f2(s struct{b int;a int}) {}
```

```
$ go run a.go 
# command-line-arguments
./a.go:3: cannot use s (type struct { a int; b int }) as type struct { b int; a int } in argument to f2
```

Note: this *does* compile:

```
package main
func main() {}
func f1(s struct{a int;b int}) { f2(s) }
func f2(s struct{a int;b int}) {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "The order of structs' fields is important on the low level" How?

This will impact the **reflection**, like [`func (v Value) Field(i int) Value`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Field):

> Field returns the i'th field of the struct v

The first field 'a' in the first structure wouldn't be the same first in the second structure.
That also will influence **serialization** with [marshaler methods (encoding package)](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/).

Answer (score 4):

> Properties of types and values
>
> [Type identity](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity)
>
> Two struct types are identical if they have the same sequence of
>   fields, and if corresponding fields have the same names, and identical
>   types, and identical tags.

The corresponding field names differ:

```
s struct{a int;b int}
```

versus

```
s struct{b int;a int}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity):

> Two struct types are identical **if they have the same sequence of fields,** and if corresponding fields have the same names, and identical types, and identical tags. Two anonymous fields are considered to have the same name. Lower-case field names from different packages are always different.

The order of structs' fields is important on the low level, so two structs with different sequence of fields cannot be safely considered equivalent.

Comment: "The order of structs' fields is important on the low level" How?

Comment: [Struct packing](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) and some forms of data serialization come to mind. Playground example of struct packing in action: http://play.golang.org/p/gc6jY6541a. See also [Data structure alignment on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Comment: Do note that Go's spec in no way guarantees the low level memory is laid out in field order. While unlikely, it's entirely legal for the compiler to completely rearrange every single field (e.g. if the compiler wanted to pack the fields a certain way to maximize memory efficiency). All the spec guarantees is that **semantically** the programmer can treat them within Go itself as an ordered sequence of named fields.